# Blocking HEAD, DELETE, etc. with lighttpd

Tags: http, lighttpd, http-headers

So I have lighttpd installed and the site it runs only needs to respond to `GET` requests.

I was wondering how I can return 405 responses with `Allow: GET` headers to anything but `GET` requests using lighttpd?

I've had a quick google but even the lighttpd doesn't turn up anything solid.

**Update**

Limiting by `$HTTP["request-method"]` works a treat.

Unfortunately when you use `url.access-deny` lighttpd sets the status code and headers as a fixed thing (403 status), regardless of if you try to add header before or after.

End result:

```
$HTTP["request-method"] =~ "^(PUT|HEAD|PATCH|DELETE)$" {
    url.access-deny = ( "" )
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since version 1.4.19, you can filter on `request-method`:

```
$HTTP["request-method"] =~ "^(PUT|POST|HEAD|PATCH|DELETE)$" {
  url.access-deny = ("")
}
```

Comment: I think you've got a typo in the regex there - "[" instead of "|".

Comment: @nickgrim good catch ! thx

Comment: Works a treat in blocking so have accepted, but it does not return a 405, but a 403 instead (I guess who cares at the end of the day).

Comment: @Sam That's right, but I don't know how to send a custom HTTP code. Maybe with [mod_setenv](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs_ModSetEnv).

Comment: @j0k ah didn't know about that module, will give it a go. Thanks for the help!